# Django model formsets and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to submit my zipped formsets using Ajax. The code works perfectly when the request is not ajax. But whenever I am trying to implement Ajax, I am getting a **ValidationError: [u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']**

My views:

```
def App(request):
    lectures = Lecture.objects.all()
    TopicFormSet = modelformset_factory(Topic, extra=0)
    SummaryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Summary, extra=0)
    tquery = Topic.objects.all()
    squery = Summary.objects.all()
    #saving formsets:
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        t_formset = TopicFormSet(request.POST)
        s_formset = SummaryFormSet(request.POST) #formset instances
        if t_formset.is_valid() and s_formset.is_valid():
            t_formset.save() and s_formset.save()
            zipped = zip(t_formset.forms, s_formset.forms) #saving them with new data
        else:
                return HttpResponse("not valid formsets, dude") # for testing purposes
    else: #request=GET
        t_formset = TopicFormSet(queryset = tquery)
        s_formset = SummaryFormSet(queryset = squery)
        zipped = zip(t_formset.forms, s_formset.forms)
    return render (request, "app.html", {"lectures" : lectures, "zipped" : zipped, "t_formset" : t_formset, "s_formset" : s_formset})
```

And my Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".mygt").click(function(){ // it's a button
    serializedData = $("#id_form-0-name").serialize(); // I didn't know how to "catch" all forms in formset so I am only serializing the first one
    $.ajax({
        url: "/app/",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}',
        success: alert(serializedData)
    })
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

P.S. I have also included csrf cookie in from this article: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax and {% csrf_token %} is present near the forms.

Edit: my html:

```
<form action = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/" method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!-- t_formset.management_form -->
        {{ t_formset.management_form }}
        <!-- t_formset.management_form -->
        {{ s_formset.management_form }}
        <!-- formsets -->
        {% for topic, summary in zipped %}
        <div id="topic">{{ topic }}</div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="mygt" />
        <br>
        <div id="summary">{{ summary }}</div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="mygt" />
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I did not know how to serialize all formset and I was only serializing the first field (for testing purposes). I was not aware of the fact that Django sends all formset and not just one field like I thought. So I replaced the

```
serializedData = $("#id_form-0-name").serialize();
```

with:

```
serializedData = $("form").serialize();
```

And the code works!

Comment: I am not sure it will work if you use {{csrf_token }} in your data option on your ajax call. I prefer using
csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val() as part of the data option. I think {{csrf_token}} renders the whole input field, while you want the value of it. Ignore me if I am wrong please :)

Comment: @Apostolos: I didn't even need to use csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}' part (I removed it), because csrf token is already rendered as an input field in the form and DJango takes care of evertyhing :)

Comment: Yes that is because you used the serialize() method. Just saying that if you won't use it I think using the val of the csrf input is the right way. Glad you solved your issue though.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include `{{t_formset.management_form}}` and `{{s_formset.management_form}}` in your template as described [here](http://goo.gl/7SeV6)?I had the same problem and i got the same answer [here](http://goo.gl/5NmsTE)

Comment: Apostolos > yes, I have included management forms long time ago..(I have now updated my question.) I have a feeling that the problem is somehow related to csrf tokens or formset instances..